# copy cell to another sheet if a different cell in the same row contains text

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to build an interactive worksheet that tracks the status of various funders at a nonprofit. I need to build a macro that copies the value of column A to a different sheet if the value of column E in the same row = "funded"

at present, I can copy the entire row, but I only need the value of column A

This is the code that I am using on a similar macro, but for a different sheet.

```
Option Compare Text

Sub copyToSheet()

Dim Cell As Range

With Sheets(1)
    For Each Cell In .Range("E1:E" & .Cells(.rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).row)
        If Cell.Value = "Upcoming" Then
            .rows(Cell.row).Copy Destination:=Sheets(2).rows(Cell.row)
        End If
    Next Cell
End With

Call deleteEmpties
End Sub
```

This works well when I need the whole row copied to another sheet, but now I need to copy only the values of certain columns to a new sheet while still testing against the value in column E

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
If Cell.Value = "Upcoming" Then
    Cell.entirerow.columns("A").Copy Destination:=Sheets(2).Cells(Cell.row, "A")
End If
```